# Is $uri/ some kind of special syntax for Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

If I have the following configuration, then request to `/` is downloading the `index.php` file directly from the server root(i.e., not passing to php-fpm).

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    root /home/hasib/playground/php/;
    server_name test.test;
    index index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/index.php =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

But, if I change the try_files line to this:

```
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

then by requesting `/`, I'm getting the expected output of index.php file(i.e., processed output of php-fpm).

I have also tried to put folder name in try_files like this:

```
            try_files $uri /myfolder/ =404;
```

but that is returning 301 redirect to `/myfolder/` when requesting for `/`, instead of trying the index.php file under `myfolder` directory.

So, my question is, is `$uri/` some kind of special syntax for Nginx? As the other configurations always serves the files directly or redirects to myfolder. But by including `$uri/` it tries to pass the index.php file to php-fpm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is invalid. The `.php` file needs to be processed in another `location` and therefore must be the last parameter of the `try_files` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Any file parameter that ends in `/` will check for the existence of a directory, so `$uri/` is not special, but the trailing `/` is. This is used to invoke `index` processing. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for more.